# Prove additive function has property f(-x)=-f(x)

Tags: calculus, proof-verification, proof-writing

So I am given a function f:R→R such that $f(x+y)=f(x)+f(y)$ for all real $x$ and $y$, and I have to prove $f(-x) = -f(x)$.

I was considering doing $3$ different cases: one where $x<0$, one where $x= 0$, and one where $x>0$ to prove this, with $y = 0$ the entire time.

This is what I've done so far:

Step $1$. Suppose $x = 1$, $y=0$

Step $2$. $f(-x+y) = -f(x)$

Step $3$. $f(-1+0) = -f(1)$

Step $4$. $f(-1) = -f(1)$

Step $5$. $-f(-1) = f(1)$ therefore by double negatives(??)

Step $6$. $f(1) = f(1)$

Not sure if what I did between Step $5$ and $6$ is legal. Thanks, in advance, for your help!

Answer (score 1):

It is not legal (you are using the fact that you are trying to prove), nor is it going to get you anywhere anyway.

Instead, take $y=-x$, so that
$$ f(x)+f(y) = f(x)+f(-x), $$
and
$$ f(x+y) = f(x-x) = f(0) = 0, $$
where the last equality follows since
$$ f(0+0) = f(0)+f(0) \quad\Leftrightarrow\quad f(0) = 2f(0) \quad\Leftrightarrow\quad f(0)=0. $$

Finally, we see that
$$f(x+y) = f(x) + f(y) \quad \Leftrightarrow \quad 0 = f(x) + f(-x) \quad \Leftrightarrow \quad f(-x) = -f(x).$$

Comment: Please do not reference other questions in answers, as it'll  be hard to follow for anyone in the future. If you absolutely have to, at least add a link.

Comment: Wouldn't you need to prove f(0) =0 also? (easily done)

Comment: Alright, I'll add it to the answer.